# Maven not adding JAR to project when using mvn compile but does when using mvn eclipse:eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

I need to download the Quartz scheduler. So I added its dependency to `pom.xml` and also I nedded `sl4j` for scheduling. So here is my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>

    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>

    <exclusions>

        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run the `mvn compile` command, it is downloading the quarts JAR but not adding to my eclipse Project. But when I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` it is adding the JAR to project. 
Why that is happening? Why `mvn compile` not adding the JAR to the Project?

Comment: There can be loads of reasons for jar not getting downloaded. Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error

Comment: There has to be an error, run maven in debug mode.

Comment: Actually its my fault. I have updated my question. Its downloading the JAR when I use `mvn compile` but not adding to the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you say it's getting downloaded on eclipse:eclipse, if you are doing a project refresh in eclipse note that doing eclipse: eclipse will modify the.classpath of the project and then only will the jar reflect. This behavior happens when the project imported is done as existing java project.

Comment: First I tried `mvn compile` but it was not downloading that JAR. But after `mvn eclipse:eclipse` it downloaded. Or after that when I refresh the project, the JAR was added to the project

Comment: Read my answer. Jar was downloaded bit not reflected in project classpath as its the Job of eclipse:eclipse refresh is still required

Comment: Yes you are right. The jAR gets downloaded when I do `mvn compile`. But why it is not adding to the Project?

Comment: Then why not `mvn eclipse:eclipse` not required for other JARs?

Comment: This dependency must have been added in pom after the project was imported in eclipse.

Comment: Yes. This dependency I added recently only.